# BST equality check

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, equals

I have a method that checks to see if a node of a BST is equal to another Node of another tree (given inside an input) -  regardless of structure.

this is what I have so far but it seems that I am missing something.

```
public boolean sameValues(BSTInterface<T> other) 
{
    if(other == null && this != null)
        return false;
    else if(other.size() == 0 && this.size() == 0)
        return true;

    Object temp = null;
    Object temp2 = null;
    while(other.preorderIterator().hasNext() && this.preorderIterator().hasNext())
    {
        temp = other.preorderIterator().next();
        temp2 = this.preorderIterator().next();

        if(temp.equals(temp2))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }   

    return false;
}
```

does anyone know a better approach to this?
Thanks.

Comment: first of all, no need to check for `this != null`, that can't happen. Now, what is size() returning? does a node contain some kind of array?> if so, shouldn't be comparing also that elements are equal()  if size != 0? 

I assume `preorderIterator().next()` returns the first child of the node. why is that relevant to the two nodes having the same value?

Comment: Can't you simply just compare both nodes' values?

Comment: From your, explanation, I agree with @ChrisTarazi - just compare the value of the node. Also, have you overridden `equals()`? If not, comparing two different but equivalent objects will not working using `Object.equals()`.

Comment: Look at your `while()` instruction. How many times can it loop...?

Comment: No limit on while for this.

Comment: BTW, how can a node be equal to a tree...?

Comment: The while loop is supposed to stop once it traverses the tree

Comment: But it has no chance to traverse a tree! Except a degenerate one... It can perform *at most* one iteration, then — whatever the comparision result is — the loop gets terminated either by `return true` or by `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while()` loop terminates in the **first** iteration due to superfluous `return false`. It should rather look somewhat like:

```
    while(other.preorderIterator().hasNext() && this.preorderIterator().hasNext())
    {
        temp = other.preorderIterator().next();
        temp2 = this.preorderIterator().next();

        if(temp.equals(temp2))    // same data found?
            return true;          // return success
        // else                   // do not return! continue!
        //    return false;
    }   

    return false;
}
```